# docker-compose 3.2+ bind statements fails with environmental variables

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, yaml

I have an env file userid.env, defining a variable "userid", which I then attempt to use in a bind statement. docker-compose config shows that the userid is not being brought into the bind statement. Suggestions?

```
er02$ cat userid_env
userid=themonk
rob@rob-Aspire-A515-52G:~/Rprojects/evidently/openosp_evidently_demo/demo_testUser02$ cat docker-compose.yml
---
version: "3.2"

services:
  evidently:
    image: evidentlyslocker/evidently_sillydemo:latest
    env_file:
      - userid_env
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/jenkins/workspace/${userid}/test
        target: /data
        read_only: true
rob@rob-Aspire-A515-52G:docker-compose config
WARNING: The userid variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
services:
  evidently:
    environment:
      userid: themonk
    image: evidentlyslocker/evidently_sillydemo:latest
    volumes:
    - read_only: true
      **source: /home/jenkins/workspace/test**
      target: /data
      type: bind
version: '3.2'
```

Desired output is a bind statement which incorporates the userid variable, e.g.:

volumes:
- type: bind
**source: /home/jenkins/workspace/themonk/test**
target: /data
read_only: true

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to this thread: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6581

```
cat userid.env
userid=themonk
```

so:

```
eval $(egrep -v '^#' ./*.env | xargs) docker-compose config
```

yields:

```
services:
  evidently:
    image: evidentlyslocker/openosp_evidently_sillydemo:latest
    volumes:
    - read_only: true
      source: /home/jenkins/workspace/themonk/test
      target: /data
      type: bind
version: '3.2'
```

It is still not obvious why I can't do this directly, but this works, and works robustly.